# php include does not work (class extends)

Tags: php

I am a starter at php. I have a php file where I want to include variable value from other php file. I put this code but it returns me error

`<? php`
`include 'xxx.php';` 
`echo "$statistics"; ?>`

```
Fatal error: Class 'Report_Form' not found in Z:\xxx.php on line 37
```

And in `xxx.php on line 37 I have "class Report_Form_xxx extends Report_Form"`

How can I get the value of the variable `$statistics` from `xxx.php`?

Comment: I dont know how your code works with a space between `<?` and `php`

Comment: include php file where Report_Form class is defiend.

Comment: if its a instance variable of Class Report_Form_xxx or Report_Form , create a new instance of above classess and access  it as echo classInstanceName->statistics and if its Class Variable(Static) access it with ClassName->statistics

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned

```
xxx.php on line 37 I have "class Report_Form_xxx extends Report_Form
```

But try to check if the class  Report_Form ***really exists*** on the file **xxx.php** Something like

```
class Report_Form
{

....

}
```